# What Is the Correct Way to Update a List with Entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity

I am trying to determine the preferred method of saving changes to a list.  I can add the list and save changes, but unless I first explicitly remove all the list items from the database, I cannot save the updated list as Entity attempts to add it regardless of existing items, resulting in a primary key violation.

```
List<Task> tasks = (The list of tasks I want to save);
MainJob job = db.Jobs.SingleOrDefault(j => j.jobId == jobId);
job.task = tasks;
db.SaveChanges();
```

My model looks like this

```
public class MainJob
{
    public int jobId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("jobId")]
    public List<Task> task { get; set; }
}
public class Task
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [JsonIgnore]
    [Required]
    public int contractId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int taskId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell EF of any Tasks which have been saved. You can usually do this by looking at the ID. e.g.

```
List<Task> tasks = (The list of tasks I want to save);

MainJob job = db.Jobs.SingleOrDefault(j => j.jobId == jobId);

job.task = tasks;

foreach (var task in tasks)
{
    if(task.contractId != 0) // New task
    {
        db.Tasks.Attach(task);
        db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified; // If modified

        // otherwise can set it to Unchanged
        // db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
    }
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Ofcourse if any tasks were deleted, you need to attach them and mark them as `EntityState.Deleted`, otherwise anything that is already in the database, will stay there.

Your other option is to delete everything for your job in the `Task` table.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to write only one line of code.

```
List<Task> tasks = (The list of tasks I want to save);
MainJob job = db.Jobs.SingleOrDefault(j => j.jobId == jobId);
job.task = tasks;

//That is what you have missed
db.Update(job);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I do not have an Update method.